# Do files with equal name conflict in unionfs (aufs)?

Tags: debian, filesystems, aufs

I just tried to mount two folders in one using `aufs` on Debian 7 wheezy. The command I issued is the following:

```
mkdir /test1
mkdir /test2
mkdir /test
mount -t aufs -o dirs=/test1:/test2 none /test
```

Then I wanted to see if files with the same name would conflict in the same folder, so I issued this:

```
touch /test1/file1.txt
touch /test2/file1.txt

echo "A" >/test1/file1.txt
echo "B" >/test2/file1.txt
```

The result is that `/test` contains only `file1.txt` containing the letter "B" (which means it is the `file1.txt` contained in `/test2`). How can the files not conflict? And which criteria does `aufs` use to choose which file to show if they have the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each underlying filesystem is assigned a precedence. If there are duplicate filenames, the one from the higher precedence filesystem is the visible one, the others are hidden.

See https://superuser.com/questions/326190/how-does-unionfs-work